# php xml parser -> Table or OPTION from SELECT

Tags: php, xml

I am looking for a way to parse something like this:

```
<xml>
    <data>
        <name>zyx</name>
        <value>xyz<value>
    </data>
    <data>
        <name>cba</name>
        <value>abc</value>
    </data>
</xml>
```

And turn it into this:

```
<SELECT>
      <OPTION VALUE="xyz">zyx</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="abc">cba</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

Using only php so that if a client was to look into my source code they would only see the select options instead of a js parser (which looks confusing and displays the location of the xml file being parsed. Is there a way to do this with php? and How? Using Variable Inputs?

```
function select($tid, $t, $xml, $name, $iid, $elname, $vname, $nname)
{

    $file = file_get_contents("modules/xml/$xml.xml");
    $select = new SimpleXMLElement($file);

    return "
        <TR>
      <TD ID=\"$tid\">
         &nbsp;$t&nbsp;
        </TD>
        <TD ID=\"$tid\">
        <SELECT NAME=\"$name\">";
   foreach($select->$elname as $options)
   {
   return"
   <OPTION VALUE=\"$OPTIONs->value\">
      $OPTIONs->name
   </OPTION>\n";
   }
        return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the example for `SimpleXMLElement()` at http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

```
$xml = "
 <xml>
  <data>
   <name>zyx</name>
   <value>xyz</value>
  </data>
  <data>
   <name>cba</name>
   <value>abc</value>
  </data>
 </xml>";

$select = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

echo "<select>";
foreach($select->data as $options){
    echo "<option value='$options->value'>$options->name</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

which returns

```
<select>
 <option value='xyz'>zyx</option>
 <option value='abc'>cba</option>
</select>
```

**edit**

If you want to load an external .xml file, then you want to use `simplexml_load_file()` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php

```
$select = simplexml_load_file('xmlFile.xml');

echo "<select>";
foreach($select->data as $options){
    echo "<option value='$options->value'>$options->name</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: can this be used to load an external document??

Comment: Yes, to load an external doc, just use `simplexml_load_file()` instead of `new SimpleXMLElement()`. I have updated my answer with that way as well.

Comment: my updated question may shed some more light on my current problem

Comment: since you are doing `foreach($select->$elname as $options)` you need to change `$OPTIONs->value` to `$options->value` and `$OPTIONs->name` to `$options->name` as `$OPTIONs` != `$options`. Also, you need to close your cell and row -> `</TD></TR>` at the end of you function.

Comment: also, unless I am wrong, `return` needs to be changed to `print` or `echo`, as after the 1st `return` in your function, nothing else will be returned.